# playing multiple videos with libvlcsharp on multiple monitors

Tags: c#, video, vlc, libvlcsharp

So i'm having a quite simple problem which doesnt seem to be trivial to solve. I found LibVLCSharp for controlling my videos from my c# program, which is exactly what i wanted. But i find the documentation to be quite complicated or non-existant.

I want to accomplish playing up to 4 different videos on 4 installed Monitors on one windows machine. I had a working example for 2 monitors right here:

```
    string[] vlcParameter1 = new string[]
    {
        @"--video-x=-1024",
        @"--video-y=1",
        @"--video-on-top",
        @"--fullscreen",
        @"--no-one-instance"
    };

    string[] vlcParameter2 = new string[]
    {
        @"--video-x=1",
        @"--video-y=1",
        @"--video-on-top",
        @"--fullscreen",
        @"--no-one-instance"
    };

    using var libvlc1 = new LibVLC(enableDebugLogs: true, vlcParameter1);
    using var libvlc2 = new LibVLC(enableDebugLogs: true, vlcParameter2);

    using var media1 = new Media(libvlc1, new Uri(@"C:\sample.mp4"));
    using var media2 = new Media(libvlc1, new Uri(@"C:\sample.mp4"));

    using var mediaplayer1 = new MediaPlayer(media1);
    using var mediaplayer2 = new MediaPlayer(media2);

    mediaplayer1.Fullscreen = false;
    mediaplayer2.Fullscreen = false;

    mediaplayer1.Play();
    mediaplayer2.Play();
```

Thats pretty simple but the FAQ from the libvlcsharp github page says to NEVER instanciate more than *one* LibVLC object. Which i'm doing there. Its working fine but i dont know about the problems.

To avoid this, i tried to use the `Media.AddOption` like this:

```
    media1.AddOption(":video-x=-1024");
    media1.AddOption(":video-y=1");
```

But that didnt work either.
Is there another simple way to display multiple videos on multiple screens?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo, both media 1&2 uses the same `libvlc1` instance. Anyway, your example looks perfectly reasonable to me, and well designed libraries should not allow incorrect usage, or should at least make it difficult. So if you have tested it and it works well enough, I would assume the documentation was incorrect.